# PowerShell - XmlElement to Escaped String

Tags: xml, powershell, escaping

Within PS I'm doing an API call which is returning data in xml format:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name             BaseType
-------- -------- ----             --------
True     False    XmlElement       System.Xml.XmlLinkedNode
```

I'm then using PS to modify/add a node and it's value using something like:

```
$resultAdminGet.Parent.Node.SubNode.Element= "<value>"
```

This all works and when I call the SubNode it returns as expected with the modified value.

The problem I have now is that I need this SubNode XmlElement to be formatted into an escaped xml string nested within the Parent so that I'd have a value similar to this in order to use the API to make an actual update:

```
<Parent>
    <Version>1.7</Version>
    <Context>(omitted )</Context>
    <MsgType>(omitted )</MsgType>
    <Type>43</Type>
    <Name>Test</Name>
    <GenericNode>&lt;GenericNode>**((ESCAPED STRING HERE))**/GenericNode></GenericNode>
</Parent>
```

Note - I may have explained/omitted sensitive data poorly and some of this terminology may be off but by using `$resultAdminGet.Parent.Node.SubNode` those are all the xml values I need to escape.

Any help/ideas how this can be accomplished?

Thanks!

Comment: Try using `[System.Security.SecurityElement]::Escape('<my text>')`.

Comment: @AdminOfThings It's just returning 'System.Xml.XmlElement'

Comment: Maybe you want `[System.Security.SecurityElement]::Escape($resultAdminGet.Parent.Node.SubNode.InnerXml)`.

Comment: Just tried 'InnerText' before you commented and got kinda close, but InnerXml worked wonderfully!  Definitely closer to this working, just need to wrap it in the proper outer elements now.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you can use the [SecurityElement.Escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securityelement.escape?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) method to replace invalid XML characters with their XML equivalents.

```
[System.Security.SecurityElement]::Escape($resultAdminGet.Parent.Node.SubNode.InnerXml)
```